# Updating SQL through prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm not getting any errors on any error logs nor is this spitting errors back at me at the function level. This isn't updating my database though.
Is this a valid statement? Upon testing (granted late at night on no sleep) I believed the statement was functional. Upon running it outside of sandbox it wasn't producing any results. Both `$username` and `$userid` are being set prior to calling this.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","db_name");
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE Users SET user =? WHERE id =?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("si", $username, $userid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    echo "<br>Username Updated<br>";
}else {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
```

Comment: `mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","db_name");` if that is your real code, that opening `mysqli` is being treated as a constant. Error reporting would have told you about it.

Comment: I was missing the $. Questioned edited.

Comment: hard to say, because we don't know where `$username, $userid` are coming from, if from a form, hardcoded, JS/Ajax. Use error reporting if you're not already doing so. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and make sure you don't have whitespace going in there also.

Comment: If this was running properly in a sandbox environment, and now not running out of sandbox.. is there a record in the Users table with the same userid that you are testing for... ?

Comment: I want to knw the result of this if($var = true) and if(true) any difference? @fred-ii     and this also if($var == true)

Comment: @devpro you shouldn't be asking questions here ;-)

Comment: You should be checking the results of the calls you are making. Any of them might fail.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this constitutes as a valid answer per say, but I found my problem. The key was indexed as a unique. This function was naming multiple rows the same thing and the index was preventing that. Doh.